# touched by Line Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I want to write a script that enemies disappear when they are shot by the "Line Renderer" emitted from the "Player".

Can anyone show me an easy example in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find information you're looking for: [Unity training: Fun with lasers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/fun-with-lasers)